# Reading barcodes from pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

I was just wondering if anyone has experience reading barcodes from a pdf file. I googled and found this bytescout reader and used the program like this

```
Reader barcodeReader = new Reader();
barcodeReader.BarcodeTypesToFind.Code39 = true;
Console.WriteLine("Reading barcode(s) from PDF");

FoundBarcode[] barcodes = barcodeReader.ReadFrom("Sample.pdf");

foreach (FoundBarcode barcode in barcodes)
    Console.WriteLine("Found barcode with type '{0}' and value '{1}'", barcode.Type, barcode.Value);
```

This doesn't output any barcodes.
Please suggest any other library I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DataMatrix](http://datamatrixnet.sourceforge.net/) is a C# library that can decode barcodes from image files and I believe it can read them from PDFs too. Here is an example of usage:

```
private string DecodeText(string sFileName)
{
    DmtxImageDecoder decoder = new DmtxImageDecoder();
    System.Drawing.Bitmap oBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(sFileName);
    List<string> oList = decoder.DecodeImage(oBitmap);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Length = 0;
    foreach (string s in oList)
    {
        sb.Append(s);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You pass in an image filename and it will decode the barcode and return the string. If DataMatrix does not read from PDFs, then you'll have to also download [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which is a library for manipulating PDFs. Using iTextSharp, you can extract the barcode from the PDF, save it as an image, then use the function above to interpret the barcode.